Spread element on initialized inline array in collection expression throws AccessViolationException
EDIT: This question describes a known issue #70708.
When creating an inline array via a constructor that assigns the elements of the array, accessing said inline array via a spread element throws a System.AccessViolationException.
For an inline array defined as:
[InlineArray(8)]
public struct InlineIntArray8
{
    private int element0;

    public InlineIntArray8()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            this[i] = i;
        }
    }
}

Then accessing the inline array in the following ways:
InlineIntArray8 inlineArray = new();
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanFromMemoryMarshal =
    MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpan(ref Unsafe.As<InlineIntArray8, int>(ref inlineArray), 8);
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanFromImplicitConversion = inlineArray;
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanWithSpreadElementFromExistingReadOnlySpan = [42, ..readOnlySpanFromImplicitConversion];
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanFromSpreadElement = [5, ..inlineArray]; // AccessViolationException

Each of these methods of creating a ReadOnlySpan<int> from the inline array work, except the last one using the spread element on the inline array. (Note that using the spread element on a ReadOnlySpan<int> that was implicitly converted from the same inline array does not throw an exception.)
If the body of the constructor is removed (such that no elements are assigned: this[i] = ...), then the spread element does not cause this exception.
Is there a reason why the inline array whose elements are initialized causes this exception when using the spread element?

This should be a bug in the compiler, because what it does is really wrong imo.
InlineIntArray8 inlineArray = new();
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanFromSpreadElement = [5, .. inlineArray]; // AccessViolationException

gets compiled into:
InlineIntArray8 inlineArray = new InlineIntArray8();
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(5);
Span<int>.Enumerator enumerator = ((Span<int>*)(&inlineArray))->GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int current = enumerator.Current;
    list.Add(current);
}
ReadOnlySpan<int> readOnlySpanFromSpreadElement = new ReadOnlySpan<int>(list.ToArray());

The really interesting line is:
Span<int>.Enumerator enumerator = ((Span<int>*)(&inlineArray))->GetEnumerator();

It basically casts very unsafely the inlineArray into Span<int>, so we would get the 00-01 for the first field of the span, i.e. the address of the reference, and 02 for the length from our example:
internal readonly ref T _reference;
private readonly int _length;

The Access Violation happens when in the Enumerator.Current we try to access that 00-01 address...
return ref _span[_index];

For fun you can set the first two elements in the inlineArray to 0, and say the third to 1 to get a NullReferenceException (assuming 64bit architecture)
EDIT: From the Github issue for this there is a work-around:

The workaround is to cast the inline array to a span directly before
using the spread operator e.g

[5, ..(ReadOnlySpan<int>)inlineArray]


Thank you for your answer. That's interesting that there is a(n unsafe) cast to Span<int> when a safe cast would invoke the implicit conversion operator, properly constructing the span object. I'll look into filing this as a GitHub issue. Thanks again for your effort looking into this!

Issue #107018

@monkey0506 It's actually interesting that the working code produces a slightly different output - using an array and Span.CopyTo, instead of the List<> and Enumerator in the wrong version.

Turns out there was an existing Issue #70708. Mine was marked as a duplicate, which is fine since it is!

@monkey0506 edited the answer to include a link to the github issue and the workaround
